# Misplaced modifier?

Tags: meaning, word-order, prepositional-phrases, modifiers, adverbials

I was wondering whether an adverbial prepositional phrase can come after the object without it modifying the verb/object in the sentence.

For example,

> The storm pelted hail with great ferocity.

In the previous sentence, am I grammatically saying that the pelting hail was ferocious?

Comment: This question would really benefit from an example sentence.  Some of us know good or bad grammar when we see it but are shaky on the nomenclature.

Comment: Yes, reason adjuncts functioning as supplements can, as in "He dropped it, with the result that it stopped working", where the _with_ PP is a supplement. Supplements are not modifiers but loosely attached items not integrated into the structure of the clause.

Comment: The question needs improvement, it seems to me. The *pelting* was ferocious, the *hail* wasn't, so "the pelting hail," which is actually the noun is not modified, it is the verb that is. HTH.

Comment: I lately lost a preposition;
It hid, I thought, beneath my chair
And angrily I cried, "Perdition!
Up from out of under there."

Correctness is my vade mecum,
And straggling phrases I abhor,
And yet I wondered, "What should he come
Up from out of under for?"
-- Morris Bishop

Comment: You're sayimg the _pelting_ was ferocious.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with fixed expressions, though a comma is usually used before the adjunct. The adverbial qualifies the whole matrix sentence.

> In the final analysis, our results need to improve or we will fail to
>   attract the necessary number of students.

> Our results need to improve or we will fail to
>   attract the necessary number of students, in the final analysis.

Comment: Huh, Edwin Ashworth?

Comment: @Edwin So the answer to the OP's question is yes, but with a qualifier. The prepositional phrase can modify the main clause (instead of the noun it follows) but it must be preceded with a comma. Right?

Comment: 'He picked up the shield with a flourish'  say would not usually be furnished with a comma. Though 'with a flourish' is ambiguous: either an adjectival post-modifier of 'shield', or an adverbial of manner. The example I chose uses the PP as a pragmatic marker, traditionally a 'sentence adverbial'; these are usually set off by commas.